# Warning passing 'char []' to parameter of type 'unsigned char *'

Tags: c, arm, keil

I am working on Keil Compiler for ARM controllers and writing code in C. I am stuck with this warning I am getting this :

```
warning : passing 'char [7]' to parameter of type 'unsigned char *'converts between pointers to integer types with different sign.
```

Routine :

```
void WriteString(unsigned char *Msg_add)
    {
        for(Lcd_pointer=0; Lcd_pointer < 16; Lcd_pointer++)
        {
            Write_lcd_data(*Msg_add);
            Msg_add++;
            if(*Msg_add == '\0')
                break;
        }
    }
```

I am passing above routine with random string :

```
WriteString("Token:");
```

The fucntions works by the way, But I am getting this warning. How to remove?

Comment: `WriteString((unsigned char*)"Token:");`

Comment: The compiler may have a switch to allow implicit conversion between pointer-to-character types

Answer (score 5):

This is the expected warning as `"Token:"` is of type `const char *`
but `void WriteString(unsigned char *Msg_add)`  is expecting `unsigned char *`

You need to type cast the argument

```
WriteString((unsigned char*) your_data);
```

Comment: Note that string literals in C are not const qualified and have type *array of char*. Naturally there's the conversion to *pointer to char* in most contexts.

Comment: I didn't mean that the function should not take const (unsigned) char pointers, but that "as "Token:" is of type const char *" is misleading. Please do make functions take const chars, if they do not intend to modify them, that's sound advice. And you are correct that you cannot modify string literals, even though they're not const.